# Is it secure to connect directly to Azure SQL

Tags: winforms, azure, database-connection

If I have a Windows Forms app that gets data from Azure SQL is it safe to connect directly to the Azure SQL with a connections string  or should I develop a Web service that the Azure SQL sits behind so  I connect to web service and the web service connects to Azure SQL.

I was thinking that someone could get hold of the connection string from with in the app when it is published or is this not possible.

Comment: Please see if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39060918/saving-to-sql-database-from-wpf/39061097#39061097.

Comment: Thanks I am not sure that would provide the solution I need.Just wondered if there was away to protect the connection string -  using encryption how?

Comment: You may find this link helpful on understanding how to encrypt configuration settings: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/53tyfkaw(v=vs.85).aspx.

Comment: I'd say this question is pretty much a duplicate of the one @GauravMantri referenced.